# How do I extract feature data from the text to the excel with python

Tags: python, excel

Recently, I get some text files, my task is to extract meaningful data from these files and organize them into excel.

The meaningful data in the text needs to be extracted as shown in figure:

[image]

Finally extract the data to the excel table like this:

[image]

My idea is to read these text files and filter, and then use the xlswriter package  to write to the xlsx file inside, but now confused I was how these documents are filtered and intercept the corresponding data written to the corresponding excel Inside the column. i need your suggestions,thank you very much.

```
import xlsxwriter
import os
'''
# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# init excel worksheet
worksheet.write('A1','module_name')
worksheet.write('B1','Source IP Adress')
worksheet.write('C1','Source Port')
worksheet.write('D1','Target Zone')
worksheet.write('E1','Target IP Adrress')
worksheet.write('F1','Target Port')
worksheet.write('G1','Protocol')
worksheet.write('H1','Action')
worksheet.write('I1','Port Description')
'''

f=open("20161223030022_running.cfg",'rb')
ff=f.readlines()
for line in ff:
    what should i do in next step
```

Comment: Are you trying to populate a list of rules based on each row in the spreadsheet? If so, then are you also trying to populate each rule with data that is found for each column that exists in the spreadsheet?

Comment: yeah,can u give me some advice?or show me some fake code

Comment: It would help if you gave a sample cfg file. You could use something like [0bin](https://0bin.net/) to upload the file to and then add a link to it to your question.